# 3d polygon - polygon intersection in python

Tags: python, intersection, shapely

I'm trying to find the intersection of two 3d polygons that I have the XYZ coordinates for.

I searched for hours but didn't found a good solution that meets my requirements.
As a final result, I want something like Shapely where I can give my XYZ coordinates of the two polygons and get as result the coordinates of the intersection.

```
# This code is just for example returns an error because Shapely only works with XY

from shapely.wkt import loads

poly = loads('POLYGON ((0 0 0, 100 0 100, 100 100 100, 0 100 0, 0 0 0))')
poly_horizontal_line = loads('POLYGON ((-50 50 -50, -50 50 150, 150 50 150, 150 50 -50, -50 50 -50))')

intersection = poly_horizontal_line.exterior.intersection(poly)

if intersection.is_empty:
   print("shapes don't intersect")
elif intersection.geom_type.startswith('Multi') or intersection.geom_type == GeometryCollection':
   for shp in intersection:
      print(shp)
else:
   print(intersection)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion or alternative library where I can achieve this with?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you want a different library, doesn't this meet your purposes?

Comment: Shapely only works with 2 axes XY and I need XYZ..

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/GouMinghao/Geometry3D) library, help you?

Comment: Hi, I came across this library but I didn't think it could solve my problem. I gave it a try and it worked eventually, thanks! I'm posting my solution also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library solved my problem: https://github.com/GouMinghao/Geometry3D

I'm posting my code here also because their aren't a lot of examples of this specific problem online:

```
from Geometry3D import *

a = Point(0,0,0)
b = Point(1,0,0)
c = Point(1,1,0)
d = Point(0.5,1.5,0)
e = Point(0.25,2,0)
f = Point(0,2,0)
plane1 = ConvexPolygon((a,b,c,d,e,f))

a1 = Point(-0.5,1.2,-0.5)
b1 = Point(1.5,1.2,-0.5)
c1 = Point(1.5,1.2,1.5)
d1 = Point(-0.5,1.2,1.5)
plane2 = ConvexPolygon((a1,b1,c1,d1))

inter = intersection(plane1,plane2)
print(inter) # results I needed



# visualize planes 
r = Renderer()
r.add((plane1,'r',2),normal_length = 0)
r.add((plane2,'b',2),normal_length = 0)
r.show()
```